# Grow partition on ubuntu server 18.04 inside virtualbox doesn't seem to work

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, lvm

These are the steps I am trying [from this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/583544/512013):

Steps I ran:

1. Run below command to get PV *(Physical Volume)* name *(Ex: `/dev/sda1`)*

```
sudo pvs
```

```
tini-wini # pvs
  PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/sda3  ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  <9,00g    0
tini-wini #
```

2. Resize the PV

```
sudo pvresize /dev/sda3
```

```
tini-wini # sudo pvresize /dev/sda3
  Physical volume "/dev/sda3" changed
  1 physical volume(s) resized or updated / 0 physical volume(s) not resized
tini-wini #
```

3. Run below command to get root logical volume name *(Filesystem value of `/` row; ex: `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root`)*

```
df -h
```

```
tini-wini # df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               948M     0  948M   0% /dev
tmpfs                              199M  1,1M  198M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  8,8G  8,2G  211M  98% /
tmpfs                              992M     0  992M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              992M     0  992M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0                          45M   45M     0 100% /snap/snapd/15314
/dev/loop1                          62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1405
/dev/loop2                          62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1376
/dev/loop3                          68M   68M     0 100% /snap/lxd/22753
/dev/loop4                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2344
/dev/loop5                          68M   68M     0 100% /snap/lxd/22526
/dev/loop6                          44M   44M     0 100% /snap/snapd/15177
/dev/loop7                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2253
/dev/sda2                          976M  207M  703M  23% /boot
tmpfs                              199M     0  199M   0% /run/user/1000
tini-wini #
```

4. Expand logical volume:

```
sudo lvextend -r -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root
```

```
tini-wini # lvextend -r -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
  Size of logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv unchanged from <9,00 GiB (2303 extents).
  Logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv successfully resized.
resize2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
The filesystem is already 2358272 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!

tini-wini #
```

With `lsblk` command it´s show me that the space in disk are there.

```
tini-wini # lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                       7:0    0 44,7M  1 loop /snap/snapd/15314
loop1                       7:1    0 61,9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1405
loop2                       7:2    0 61,9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1376
loop3                       7:3    0 67,8M  1 loop /snap/lxd/22753
loop4                       7:4    0 55,5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2344
loop5                       7:5    0 67,9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/22526
loop6                       7:6    0 43,6M  1 loop /snap/snapd/15177
loop7                       7:7    0 55,5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2253
sda                         8:0    0   21G  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0    1M  0 part
├─sda2                      8:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0    9G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0    9G  0 lvm  /
sr0                        11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
tini-wini #
```

What do I need to do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PFree output is 0 so you have no space available within sda3. You need to:

1. Backup any data you cannot afford to loose.
2. Boot the machine from an Ubuntu install iso , choose “try Ubuntu” and run GParted in the live environment.
3. Using GParted you should be able to expand sda3 to make use of all the unallocated space on sda.
4. Reboot and repeat the steps you describe in your question to add the new space to the volume group. I find this tutorial particularly helpful for LVM. https://www.tecmint.com/extend-and-reduce-lvms-in-linux/

Good luck!